# Animated ImageView is overlapped by overlay view

Tags: android, android-animation

I have created an overlay oval view on camera preview.

[image: aaa]

I'm trying to animate an ImageView and translate it into the center of the oval. Almost everything works fine, the single problem that remains is that the animated ImageView is overlapped by the oval just like you can see in this gif: https://i.stack.imgur.com/THyNe.jpg (sorry for the resolution).

I've tried to set z index, set elevation, to bring the view upfront but none of this work. Any idea how can i set the view to be above the oval view and not overlapped by it? Thank you!

Overlay oval view:

```
public class OverlayView extends View {
private Paint transparentBackground;
private Paint eraser;
private Paint borderPaint;
private float horizontalMargin;
private float verticalMargin;

private float WIDTH_FACTOR = 2.9f;
private float HEIGHT_FACTOR = 12f;

public OverlayView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public OverlayView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public OverlayView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    if (horizontalMargin == 0) {
        horizontalMargin = getMeasuredWidth() / WIDTH_FACTOR;
    }

    if (verticalMargin == 0) {
        verticalMargin = getMeasuredHeight() / HEIGHT_FACTOR;
    }

    Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight());
    canvas.drawRect(rect, transparentBackground);

    canvas.drawArc(new RectF(
            horizontalMargin,
            verticalMargin,
            getMeasuredWidth() - horizontalMargin,
            getMeasuredHeight() - verticalMargin), 0, 360, true, borderPaint);

    canvas.drawArc(new RectF(
                    horizontalMargin,
                    verticalMargin,
                    getMeasuredWidth() - horizontalMargin,
                    getMeasuredHeight() - verticalMargin),
            0, 360, true, eraser);

}

public void init(int borderColor, float horizontalMargin, float verticalMargin) {
    this.horizontalMargin = horizontalMargin;
    this.verticalMargin = verticalMargin;

    transparentBackground = new Paint();
    transparentBackground.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    transparentBackground.setAlpha(200);
    transparentBackground.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    borderPaint = new Paint();
    borderPaint.setColor(borderColor);
    borderPaint.setStrokeWidth(15);
    borderPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

    eraser = new Paint();
    eraser.setAntiAlias(true);
    eraser.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
    eraser.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
 }
}
```

Animation function:

```
private void moveViewToScreenCenter( View view )
{
    final RelativeLayout root = (RelativeLayout) findViewById( R.id.relativeLayoutRoot );
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics( dm );
    int statusBarOffset = dm.heightPixels - root.getMeasuredHeight();

    int originalPos[] = new int[2];
    view.getLocationOnScreen( originalPos );

    int xDest = dm.widthPixels/2;
    xDest -= (view.getMeasuredWidth()/2);
    int yDest = dm.heightPixels/2 - (view.getMeasuredHeight()/2) - statusBarOffset;

    faceView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    Toast.makeText(this, "Please place your face within the oval.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation( 0, xDest - originalPos[0] , 0, yDest - originalPos[1] );
    anim.setDuration(1000);
    view.startAnimation(anim);
}
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutRoot"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<net.ossrs.yasea.SrsCameraView
    android:id="@+id/glsurfaceview_camera"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/faceView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/id_face"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by removing the overlay view from the main activity and moving it to a DialogFragment. This class will display the overlay view and the animation. When the activity is created I show the dialog fragment and on the **onAnimationEnd** event i dismiss the dialog. Right now there aren't any overlapped view problems since I display the new dialog over the current activity and the animation is above all layout elements.